# Django cannot find my base template, but it's there

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am "trying" to develop a Django project with Bootstrap. Because each page requires the exact same Bootstrap code, it looks more logical to me to have one base template at project level.

Learning from [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492617/base-template-for-all-apps-in-django) and [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246150/django-global-base-html-template), here's the content of my project files:

settings.py

```
'DIRS': [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')),],
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
]
```

views.py

```
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'homepage/index.html')
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Hello from index.html{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
This is from the index.html
{% endblock %}
```

Now when I browse the homepage of site (localhost:8000) I get TemplateDoesNotExist error. When I look at the error details I see this:

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: D:\Django Projects\omidshojaee.com\omidshojaee_com\templates\base.html (Source does not exist)
```

**So Django is looking into the correct folder, and base.html is there (I can see it with my own eyes), so why Django cannot load it?**

Edit: I should have explained the folder structure. It looks like this:

index.html inside omidshojaee_com(this is the project name)/homepage(this is the app name)/templates/homepage/

base.html inside omidshojaee_com/templates/

What I want is to have one base.html shared between all apps.

Comment: can you show the screenshot of the folder structure?

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set 'templates' folder as the directory for your templates. So in your view should look like this

```
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

And your **index.html** file should be in templates folder

Comment: And your base.html should be in templates folder

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I want. I want index.html to be in the templates folder of its own app, and base.html to be in the templates folder of the project. Currently, index.html is in homepage(app name)/templates/homepage and base.html file is in omidshojaee_com(project)/templates/. My goal is to have one base.html shared between all apps.

Comment: then in settings.py you have to add both directories 


`'DIRS': [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'homepage/templates'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'omidshojaee_com/templates'),
],`

Comment: Thanks you were partially right. I addedd "omidshojaee_com/templates" and it solved the issue.

Comment: Another question. Right now my DIRS is os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'omidshojaee_com/templates') and it works. But what happens when I move it to the production server and 'omidshojaee_com' is not a valid path anymore? Is there any variable for project folder?

Comment: Could you please tell a bit more brief about what you mean?

Comment: Sorry for asking another question. To solve my problem I added PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) to my settings. This works but I'm not sure this is a proper approach?